# Best approach for MVC WebAPI DTO Model Binding With Derived Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

What is the best approach for designing a DTO for MVC or Web Api Model Binding (haven't decided which to use yet) that will use Entities Framework given the following model:

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<ActorPhone> ActorPhones { get; set; }
    public List<ActorEmail> ActorEmails { get; set; }
    public List<ActorAddress> ActorAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class ActorAddress
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

}

public class ActorEmail
{
    public int ActorEmailId { get; set; }
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public enum ActorPhoneType
{
    HomePhone,
    WorkPhone,
    Fax
}
public abstract class ActorPhone
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public int ActorPhoneId { get; set; }
    public ActorPhoneType PhoneType { get; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public ActorPhone(ActorPhoneType phoneType)
    {
        this.PhoneType = phoneType;
    }

}
public class ActorHomePhone : ActorPhone
{
    public ActorHomePhone() : base(ActorPhoneType.HomePhone) { }

}
public class ActorWorkPhone : ActorPhone
{
    public ActorWorkPhone() : base(ActorPhoneType.WorkPhone) { }

}
public class ActorFax : ActorPhone
{
    public ActorFax() : base(ActorPhoneType.Fax) { }

}
```

While Address and Email can have multiple Entities and Actor should only have one Home Phone, one Work Phone and one Fax.

The database has a table ActorPhones from which the derived types will be stored.

How do I approach model binding in an MVC or Web API controller. What should the form input fields be named?

For example, there is this approach:

```
<input name="Actor.ActorPhones[0].Phone" type="text"/>
```

And this approach:

```
 <input name="Actor.HomePhone.Phone" type="text"/>
```

There is also the approach of exposing each as a string property on Actor.

```
 public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public List<ActorEmail> ActorEmails { get; set; }
    public List<ActorAddress> ActorAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

And using:

```
<input name="Actor.HomePhone" type="text"/>
<input name="Actor.WorkPhone" type="text"/>
<input name="Actor.Fax" type="text"/>
```

Using the first, I would need an additional input for the phone type. The second and third would require custom logic to bind the model to the dbset.

Additionally, there may be millions of actors in the database and for performance reasons there should not be empty phone numbers. The first and third approach would also require custom logic to check the ActorPhones list by PhoneType and removing or adding ActorPhone entities and their underlying DBSets. If an actor doesn't have, for example, a Fax number record in the database the one shouldn't be added so custom logic would be needed.

So let's say we use the first approach and our first Actor has a home phone only the view can render the following on the form easily form  the list of Actor Phones in the model:

```
<input name="Actor.ActorPhones[0].Phone" type="text" required/>
<input name="Actor.ActorPhones[0].PhoneType" type="hidden" value="HomePhone"/>
```

Using the first approach for a second actor that has a home phone and a work phone so the form would have:

```
<input name="Actor.ActorPhones[0].Phone" type="text" required/>
<input name="Actor.ActorPhones[0].PhoneType" type="hidden" value="HomePhone"/>
<input name="Actor.ActorPhones[0].Phone" type="text" required/>
<input name="Actor.ActorPhones[1].PhoneType" type="hidden" value="WorkPhone"/>
```

Using this approach the controller the view can render the model on the form easily.

Using the second approach, our view needs to see if each of the `Actor.HomePhone`,`Actor.WorkPhone`, or `Actor.Fax` navigation properties is not null and if they aren't render the corresponding `<input name="Actor.HomePhone.Phone" type="text"/>`, `<input name="Actor.WorkPhone.Phone" type="text"/>` or `<input name="Actor.Fax.Phone" type="text"/>`. This would need custom logic, perhaps through a service on the server side but lends itself to using the Factory design pattern.

Using the third approach, `Actor.HomePhone`, `Actor.WorkPhone`, `Actor.Fax` as string properties, the view would need to check if the fields are null and the values aren't emtpy render the corresponding `<input name="Actor.HomePhone" type="text"/>`, `<input name="Actor.WorkPhone" type="text"/>` or `<input name="Actor.Fax" type="text"/>` fields. Additionally on the server side custom logic would be needed, for example through a service. But I am unsure of the best design pattern to use taking this approach. The third approach also wasn't implemented directly in the database to save space. If the home phone, work phone and fax where added to the actors table and each was defined as a varchar(20) then the database would require an additional 20*3*1,000,000 =60,000,000 bytes or 60 mb per million records.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve. But if you allow only one phone number per type then have your Model keep discrete properties for each `public class ActorForm() { int HomePhone { get;set; } int WorkPhone { get;set; } int Fax { get; set; } }`. I'd even simply Phone into primitive types. Then have your controller (or even better, another service class) build your entity types.

Comment: I updated the question adding your suggested approach and the considerations. +1 for asking it. Initially i discounted this method as I am trying to follow best practices for design patterns. The first approach maps directly to the db model and the second approach lends its self to the factory pattern. I am not sure what design pattern to use following this approach, or apply one such as the factory pattern, besides using if statements in the service logic to test if the properties are null.